# Was Edgar Cayce visited by Rockefeller and other important figures from that era?

Tags: history, psychics

Edgar Cayce was an American psychic who was famous during the early 20th century. He was notorious for giving readings during an alleged trance state he entered while sleeping. There’s a foundation that stores the readings that were recorded later in his “career” and they have been a topic of debate among his followers and skeptics.

During the documentary; "[Edgar Cayce - An American Prophet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2eNVgjQ9-g)", on [New Heaven](http://www.nhne.com/misc/edgarcayce.html), and [Barnes & Noble](http://www.nhne.com/misc/edgarcayce.html), it is mentioned that among his visitors were some important figures of the era like Nelson Rockefeller.

Is there any truth in these claims?

Comment: Could you add a link to "a documentary", give name to it, and preferably add a link to it. Also it would be nice if you could link "some places on the internet" and quote the relevant parts from the links.

Comment: @Wertilq Some "facts" mentioned here http://www.nhne.com/misc/edgarcayce.html

Comment: Sorry for being so vague in my question. I updated it adding sources.

Comment: I cleaned things up a bit, it's better to not write "Edit:", since questions on StackExchange often is 'timeless', then it's better to make whole question/answer as nice as possible, and like no one have seen it before. If you want to further improve the question you should quote relevant parts from the page to make it easier for others to see the claims.